# Most efficient (cost & time) way to get a good Gavel of Judgement

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I'm looking for a strong gavel to play the HotA build with my season barb but I'm only finding mediocre ones. If I wanted to dedicate time specifically towards creating/finding a strong gavel, what would be the most efficient route?

Simply rifting and waiting for one to drop seems inefficient. What about cube-rerolling an existing gavel vs. upgrading 2h mighty weapons, how do they compare? Could someone create a numerical breakdown of the possible options?

This question could use a "Theorycrafting" tag, but I couldn't create it.

---

**TL;DR:** Looking for the most cost and time efficient way to roll loads of gavels in a manageable timeframe, would like numerical breakdown of options.

Comment: Probably cube re-rolling will be better. If you upgrade existing stuff, you only have a 1:4 chance of getting the gavel.

Comment: Considering how few legendary 2 handed mighty weapons there are, upgrading rares is pretty cost effective. Reforging an existing Gavel is an option, but I find that it's a lot worse, due to the amount of souls you need. Salvaging the non-gavels you get from upgrading rares can help you get a couple reforges as well though.

Comment: @Chippies thats what I thought initially. I should investigate if this, in its entirety (finding rare 2h mighty, spending mats and breaths, Chance for a gavel to drop), is more efficient than the accepted answer below with guaranteed 4+ gavels per hour with a Chance for ancients.

Comment: There are only 5 legendary 2handed mighty weapons, so (according to [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16w3GylxL3mM1RFE7wtQT2xOv41xgkBxe9trTlpWe-vE/pubhtml#)) it will take approx 125 breaths to get a gavel.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to combine both upgrading and reforging, so running public bounties would be your best choice. May even throw in some Kadala action, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you already have one**, 4 person spit bonus bounties is the best way to go.

With a halfway decent squad, you can 20+ materials in an hour. Let's assume you get 20.

That's like finding 4 GoJ's, each one with a 10% chance to be ancient per hour.

**If you don't have one**, just do rifts or greater rifts (whichever you find more enjoyable) and spend all of your bloodshards on weapons.

Comment: But what about Forgotten Souls? At the rate I will be receiving bounty materials, sustaining enough souls will be difficult even with a head start, right?

Comment: Legendaries that you don't need actually start to drop quite a bit after a while. You'll be scrapping 99% of all of the legendaries you find after a bit of playing. You'll even find some while doing bounties because you'll get 1-2 per bonus act you complete.

Comment: It will take a lot more than 1 full bounty run to get 50 souls, so you'll run out of souls much sooner than act materials. Don't forget you also need some souls for rerolling stats after you get the weapon (which can take a lot of souls to get the rolls you want if you're not very lucky)